# Functionality of `detach()` in PyTorch for this specific case

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I know that `detach()` is used for detaching a variable from the computational graph. In that context, are the following expressions `x = x - torch.mean(x, dim=0).detach()` and `x = x - torch.mean(x, dim=0)` equivalent? I just want to subtract the mean out, don't want to pass gradients through the average calculation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not `detach` the mean, then you have lateral dependencies between all elements in the batch (dim=0) when estimating the gradient.